# Dúvida de como utilizar os pacotes no java

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um *import* de um *package* no java, porém estou com muita dúvida e não consigo fazê-la.

O problema é o seguinte, tenho um *package* no seguinte endereço:

```
C:\projetos_de_programacao_do_atom\classes\carro
```

Enquanto eu deixo os arquivos .java no endereço:

```
C:\projetos_de_programacao_do_atom\projetos.em.java
```

Mas quando eu compilo ele pelo console aparece o seguinte resultado:

> ```
> import classes.carro.* ;
> ^
> CarroTeste.java:12: error: cannot access Carro
>     Carro carro = new Carro (  ) ;
>     ^
>   bad source file: .\Carro.java
>     file does not contain class Carro
>     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
> 2 errors
> ```

Os códigos estão abaixo para vocês darem uma olhada:

CarroTeste.java:

```java
import java.util.* ;
import classes.carro.* ;

public class CarroTeste
{

  public static void main ( String [ ] args )
  {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner ( System.in ) ;

    Carro carro = new Carro (  ) ;

  }

}
```

O arquivo que irei importar será o `Carro.class` e seu arquivo java será:

```java
package classes.carro ;

public class Carro
{

  String placa ;
  String modelo ;
  String velocidadeMaxima ;

}
```

Comment: Como você está compilando? Qual comando?

Comment: eu estou o comando : javac -d .. (nome do arquivo ).java . Ele compila normal este outro arquivo, apenas quando vou chamá- lo que no arquivo CarroTeste que ele dá erro de compilação

Comment: Mostre o comando real que está utilizando.

Comment: para o arquivo do CarroTeste, eu usei tanto  javac CarroTeste.java quanto javac -d .. CarroTeste.java

Comment: Quando arquivos são dependentes de outros, você não pode compilar separadamente assim, precisa compilar eles em ordem dos que não dependem de outros para os que dependem, ou todos juntos. Esse deve ser o motivo do erro, com certeza, mas se você não explicar completamente como está ccompilando fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: então, eu tentei fazer essas duas medidas, porém deu erro do mesmo jeito

Comment: Coloque na pergunta os comandos que você usa para tentar compilar exatamente da forma como você os digita sem mais e nem menos.

Comment: @Articuno Martelei a pergunta. Concorda?

Comment: @VictorStafusa concordo, pela falta de clareza do autor, entendo que é o mesmo problema da outra pergunta.